# Alias Name for unknown SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, alias

I am trying to give alias name in below query:

```
select x.* as rand_name , @rownum := @rownum + 1 as num from ( select t.names
from mask_data_name_dist t ) x, (select 
@rownum := 0) r
```

The above query is wrong coz I am trying to give alias name **rand_name** to **x.*** 
Is there a way I can do that ??
**Note**: I cannot touch sub-query, Inner query is dynamic and changes frequently. Just for example I have hardcoded a simple select statement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause. This restriction is  imposed because when the WHERE code is executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

check mysql documentation:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't give an alias to the `*` operator, only to a single column:

```
SELECT rand_name , @rownum := @rownum + 1 as num
FROM   (SELECT t.names AS rand_name -- Note the alias here.
        FROM   mask_data_name_dist t ) x, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

EDIT:
Since the inner query cannot be touched, the same could be applied to the outer query:

```
select x.names as rand_name , -- note the explicit column name
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 as num 
from   (select t.names mask_data_name_dist t ) x, 
       (select @rownum := 0) r
```

Comment: Thank you for ur quick response. However, my problem is somewhat different. Please look into NOTE section in my question (Pardon me if I was not clear earlier)

Comment: thxs, but as I mentioned before the query is dynamic so I cannot edit it hence I cannot know what column_name appears. Hope you understand my request.

Answer (score 0):

`x.*` means: all columns in the table `x`. It is a collection, you can not add alias to a collection in SQL. Add the proper column name to the `SELECT` list and add an alias to that column OR add the alias in the subquery

```
select
  x.*
  , @rownum := @rownum + 1 as num
from (
  select t.names AS rand_name
  from mask_data_name_dist t
) x,
(
  select 
  @rownum := 0
) r
```

Comment: Thank you for ur quick response. However, my problem is somewhat different. Please look into NOTE section in my question (Pardon me if I was not clear earlier)

Comment: Anyway, you can not add alias to a collection (x.*). Generate your query with the required aliases. The queries with placeholders (*) in the SELECT list could be dangerous, if you are usint their results in other applications. Proper field list in the SELECT part is the best way to achieve your goal.